# how to draw square after load the application in iphone(graphics)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, graphics, animation

how to draw square after load the application in iphone(graphics) ?(I know how to draw shapes but i exactly want to show draw shape after my app. launch what can i do) and also want to fill color after app. launch ?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly then you are asking about splash screen of iPhone app, i.e. Loading screen, if so, then you can do it very easily.
You just need to prepare a 320x460 (if no status bar in the app then 320x480) image, save it with "Default.png" name, and include in project using Xcode(add in resource folder). This image will be shown on iPhone screen as soon as your app is launched and will remain in the screen until you get callback at "applicationDidFinishLaunching"

but if you were asking something different then please elaborate more about your question...